# Windows Smart screen error on 7 zip self extracted file

Tags: smartscreen

I have created a code signed self extracted installer using 7 zip and upload that installer to website for download. I can download the file from machine but the issue is that I am getting a smart screen error while executing from the windows 8 machine. I have already applied code signing certificate for the 7 zip self extracted file. But why this message occurring . How can I avoid this message for other users?

I am attaching the screen shot of the smart screen error.
[image]

Answer (score 1):

There is no way to remove the SmartScreen message for **unpopular** software without user interaction when Windows is in its default configuration.

If enough people download and run your .exe then the SmartScreen block will go away. Microsoft does not specify how many downloads are required in their [FAQ](https://web.archive.org/web/20120202174001/http://windows.microsoft.com/en-US/windows7/SmartScreen-Filter-frequently-asked-questions-IE9):

> When you download a program from the Internet, SmartScreen Filter will check the program against a list of programs that are downloaded by a significant number of other Internet Explorer users and a list of programs that are known to be unsafe. If the program you're downloading isn't on either list, SmartScreen Filter will display a warning that the file isn't "commonly downloaded."

Removing the "[Mark of the Web](https://textslashplain.com/2016/04/04/downloads-and-the-mark-of-the-web/)" by unblocking it in the files properties should also prevent the SmartScreen message.

Comment: In addition, you could get an EV certificate to build up instant reputation.

Answer (score 0):

See if the App (EXE) blocked by Windows Smart Screen is properly signed and timestamped using a **SHA26** Certificate from an authorized CA.

Comment: Yes. We have used Godaddy code signing certificate and I can see the publisher name and their correct certificate in the windows smart screen.